# La imagen con display none quiero que no se cargue

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, html5

Tengo una duda, estoy optimizando un sitio web y en la versión mobile estoy poniendo imágenes de menor tamaño y por lo tanto estoy ocultando con display none de CSS la imagen desktop.
El problema mío es que por más que le ponga display none a la imagen de desktop se sigue cargan aunque no se vea.
De qué forma puedo hacer para que no se cargue la imagen desktop en la versión mobile pero que al agrandar la pantalla si se cargue la versión desktop

Comment: ¿Puedes nombrar las imágenes como quieras? porque si usas un patrón, no tienes que nombrar una a una las imagenes, por ejemplo yo uso en móviles: `nombreimagen_sm.jpg` en tablets o smartphones grandes: `nombreimagen_md.jpg` y en grandes resoluciones `nombreimagen_lg.jpg`. Así puedes con javascript, buscar todas las imágenes, impedir que cargen y que dependiendo de cada resolución, añada al final de la ruta del img la respectiva sigla y ahí si cargarla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias utilizar javascript para cargar la imagen que desees, te quedaria asi:

supón que tienes una etiqueta imagen asi:

```
<img id='img_bg'>
```

Luego atiendes el evento cuando se redimenciona la pantalla:

```
$(function() { 
    reDim() //llamo aquí la función para que compruebe con el onLoad de la pagina las dimensiones cuando se cargue

    $( window ).resize(function() { // cada vez que se re dimensiona la pantalla compruebas en que dimensión esta para cargar la imagen que debe ser
      reDim()
   });

  function reDim(){

     if( window.innerWidth >= 768){
               $('#img_bg').prop('src','/desktop.png')
        }else{

           switch(window.innerWidth) {
               case 600:
                  $('#img_bg').prop('src','/otra1.png')
                  break;
               case 500:
                  $('#img_bg').prop('src','/otra2.png')
                  break;
               case 400:
                  $('#img_bg').prop('src','/otra3.png')
                  break;
               case 300:
                  $('#img_bg').prop('src','/otra4.png')
                  break;
               default:
                  $('#img_bg').prop('src','/otra5.png')
           }
       }

  }
});
```

> Nota: Debes utilizar `jquery` para el código anterior.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda! pero tengo otro problema, son como 100 imágenes las que debo adaptar, se pondrá pesado el sitio si genero una función por cada imagen que debo adaptar?

Comment: no necesariamente deberías generar una funcion para cada resolución, dependes del ancho y largo , del ancho nada mas , o del largo nada mas , dime tus opciones para acomodar la respuesta a tus necesidades.

Comment: cuando sea mayor a 768px de width que se cargue la imagen desktop y de lo contrario la mobile, la altura no me haría falta evaluarla. Mi problema es que son varias imágenes a adaptar y las obtengo con un loop de wordpress

Comment: te edite la respuesta , suponiendo varias dimensiones, pero si la ruta de las imágenes vienen de un loop, ya habría que ver como llegan, de que forma y cuando llamar a cada posición del loop

Comment: bueno, en base a tu solución la adaptare a lo que necesito, gracias!

Comment: de nada , ten en cuenta que podrías tomar como opción para eliminarte tantas rutas e imágenes , usar imágenes SVG que se adaptan fácilmente a distintas resoluciones